# How to solved Segmentation fault when read the next video frame on centos

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture, centos6

I run this program on Centos6.8, I always got ***Segmentation fault*** (core dumped)

I also used **GDB** to debug,it says

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
memcpy () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/memcpy.S:398
398     movq    48(%rsi), %r13
```

But when I run this **same** program on my Ubuntu 18.04, it worked great.

Does anything I miss install on Centos, or I need to change another API to read frame.

BTW, I can read four frames at the beginning, after that, I got Segmentation fault.

Opencv version is 2.4.9

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Mat image;
    int a;
    VideoCapture video("15_41_24_24670.avi");
    int i = 0;
    try{
        while(true){
            video >> image;
            if(image.empty())
                break;
            cout << i++ <<endl;
        }
    }
    catch(std::exception& e){
        std::cerr << "Exception caught : " << e.what() << std::endl;
        cout<<"error"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    cout<<"successful"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: You probably miss some video codecs. Try to add a try/catch block in main to catch any exceptions and print them.

Comment: Try compiling with the `-fsanitize=address` option to see more information on where the memory error is.

Comment: Take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault), it may help you understand what going on.

Comment: It would also be helpful to see the stack trace.

Comment: @schorsch_76 I use try/catch but didn't print any other error ?

Comment: Try to set backend for VideoCapture: VideoCapture video("15_41_24_24670.avi", cv::CAP_FFMPEG); or VideoCapture video("15_41_24_24670.avi", cv::CAP_GSTREAMER); or anything else

Comment: @Nuzhny my opencv is 2.4.9. It don't have backend setting. But i update to 3.1.0. fortunately,It works. appreciate for you. Thanks you so much.

Comment: Btw, you can answer below.I will accept this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set backend for VideoCapture:

VideoCapture video("15_41_24_24670.avi", cv::CAP_FFMPEG);

or

VideoCapture video("15_41_24_24670.avi", cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);

or anything else